# Calculating date fields in MySQL from VB.Net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am working with VB.Net and Mysql database. I have two tables called: CUSTOMER, DVD_SOFT and RENT in mysql database.

CUSTOMER: cust_id, name, phone, email>
DVD_SOFT: dvd_id, dvd_name, dvd_desc, rent_price_per_day
RENT: cust_id, dvd_id, retal_date, return_date, total_fee

I have done the total_fee calculation  that is:

> total_fee = DateDiff(dateInterval.day, rental_date, return_date)*rent_price_per_day>

But I need to add penalty fee to the total_fee itself when the Customer Return_date is Exceeded.
I want like as follows from vb.net to mysql

> total_fee  = (rent_price_perday*exceeded_date)+total_fee>